# Python optparse, having one option depends on another

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to get the following to work?
What I am looking for, is to have a value of one option, based on the value of another.

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("--file-name", default="/foo/bar", dest="file_name")

parser.add_option("--file-action", 
    default="cp %s /bar/baz" % (options.file_name), 
    dest="fileaction")

options, args = parser.parse_args()
```

Obviously, as it is at the moment it will not work, since

**local variable 'options' referenced before assignment**

Comment: `optparse` module is deprecated since Python 2.7. You can consider using `argparse` instead (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) which is also available for Python 2.x: `pip install argparse`

Comment: thanks for the comment, however, changing current codebase is not on the list ;-)

Comment: I don't think you have thought this through, firstly, the file-action should not include the file-name, else there is no reason to include a file-name as a parameter in the first place. also, if it is your intention to have a script which receives a file-name a file-action and then performs the action on the file, why not simply have 3 parameters "file-name" "file-command" "file-arguments" and then simply put them together as you want?

Comment: @InbarRose `file-name` and `file-actions` are here for the sake of the example, those are not the real use in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have them both:

```
parser.add_option("--file-name", dest="file_name")
parser.add_option("--file-action", dest="file_action")
```

you can use simple logic.

```
if options.file_name:
    #do code relating to file_action
```

or even

```
if options.file_action and not options.file_name:
    raise ValueError("No Filename specified")
# do your code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to massage the default later. If the option is the default, then do the massaging:

```
parser.add_option("--file-action", 
    default="cp <filename> /bar/baz", 
    dest="fileaction")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.fileaction == "cp <filename> /bar/baz":
    options.fileaction = "cp %s /bar/baz" % (options.file_name)
```

That said, in this example, fileaction and filename seem to conflict, so that it is pointless to set both at the same time, they'll overwrite each other in ways that are not obvious. I'd let fileaction default to `"cp"`, and add a `--action-target` for `'/bar/baz'` and then just construct the call from these pieces.

Comment: The only problem with that solution is the `__default__` value will appear in the help making it a little bit ugly.

Comment: @DawidFatyga: True. Actually, come to think of it, you don't even need a marker. As long as it resolved to default, it will work. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: okay - what happens when there is a file-action, how will it be set to include the filename? - also, since when can one pass arguments to optparse with spaces seperating words of the same argument?

Comment: @InbarRose: You can have quotes, can't you? And my point is to *not* include the filename in the file-action.

Answer (score 0):

Your parser is a handler. It will explain python what you will do with the command line recieved when the programme is launch. Therefore, it is incorrect to have a dependance in your options.

What I advise you, is to deal with the default behaviour in your code. You can do something like :

```
parser.add_option("--file-action", 
default=None, 
dest="fileaction")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

# Manage the default behaviour
if not options.fileaction:
    fileaction = "cp %s /bar/baz" % (options.file_name)
    # You could then use fileaction the way you would use options.fileaction
```